# Move all coins from an address via RPC

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, bitcoin-core, json-rpc, transaction-fees

Let's say I generated some coins with a given address and I want to send a specific amount of coins to a specific addresses, and move the remaining balance to another specific address. I want to do it all using bitcoind and an RPC call. It would be easy if it wasn't for the variable fee, based on the size of the transaction; just calculate the difference between what is in the first address and what needs to be paid out, and send the rest to the other address.

Is there some way to set an address in bitcoind that is to receive all the change, or to get some information on what the fee for the given transaction should be?

Comment: I could explain it in detail here to you, but I think the API reference speaks for itself. It's all possible and fairly easy once familiar with the API.